# Chartboost is not shown more than one time

Tags: macos, android-studio, cocos2d-x, chartboost

I am new in cocos2dx.Now i add the chartboost in androidstudio.
But chartboost come only one time then after is not shown permanantly.I call the delegate for log print .
Log is display below.

Request /interstitial/get succeeded. Response code: 200, body: {"message":"No publisher campaigns found","status":404}

W/network failure﹕ request /interstitial/get failed with error HTTP_NOT_FOUND: 404 error from server

I/Chartboost﹕ DID FAIL TO LOAD INTERSTITIAL 'Default Error: NO_AD_FOUND

Answer (score 1):

First try using the test id and then campaigns your project.And after add the campaigns ,wait for 20 miniut .Run your project you will get chartboost.For more  detail  [go this page](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/204930539-Creating-a-Publishing-Campaign)

Answer (score 0):

Log exactly explains what's happening. You aren't getting any ads, because you exhausted all what could be served. I was using chartboost a lot and it was always the same - it showed 1, 2 or few times (sometimes even not once) and then no ads for some long time.

You should check out test mode. Or just use admob/whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked after I did the following steps here:

1. Login Chartboost
2. click App>Overview
3. Click app name
4. Click More Apps Page
5. Enter your app name to the Add all apps field on the right side
6. Click SAVE

[source](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/40644-chartboost-error-404/)